# My app won't connect to SQL Server while in diferent subnet

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling to connect my app to a SQL server whitch is in another subnet. I'm using connection string like that:

```
192.168.2.xxx\nameOfTheInstance
```

and everything works fine from the same subnet, but if my PC has ip adress like 192.168.3.1/24 my app won't connect to the server. Oddly, when i use the same exact connection string in ssms in the same PC configuration, it works perfectly well.

We've eliminated network specific errors, so it has to Windows Firewall or some server setting that i don't know of.

Server is Windows Server 2019 (1809) on a phisical machine, and client can be literaly every Windows PC.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL 
Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - 
Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Comment: For starters, it should be `server\instance`, not `server/instance`. Second, if you're using instance names rather than ports (`tcp:server,port`), the SQL Server Browser service needs to be running, and the network needs to be configured to allow UDP packets on port 1434. As this is UDP and not TCP, firewalls and routers may be pickier about allowing the return packets.

Comment: I am inclined to vote to close - this sounds way more not like a proglramming question than simply as "learn how to do routing between subnets", which is a basic system administraiton question. You should literallly ignore everything app side and start asking this on a place for network admin (serverfault, superuser) with full network diagrams and routing table dumps. I bet, ping also does not work ;)

Comment: @TomTom ping, rdp, http, and everythig you can think of DOES work, but sql is so shy of strangers

Comment: Specify the port number instead of instance name in the connection string to avoid the need for the SQL Server Browser and UDP to get involved (e.g. `192.168.2.xxx,1433`). Note this port number is just an example since the port number may be other than the default 1433 port with a named instance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. SQL server browser was answering from second nic. Problem solved.